# Problem at json_prolog

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i'm trying to run

> rosrun json_prolog json_prolog comp_germandeli

i got that message

> find: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/': No such file or directory
> Cannot find libjsig ... maybe you need to set JAVA_HOME?

and i already have JAVA_HOME...what shall i do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45702/problem--at-json_prolog/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was geeting a similar error while issuing the command $rosrun json_prolog json_prolog ias_semantic_map

The result was:
find: `/jre/lib/': No such file or directory
Cannot find libjsig ... maybe you need to set JAVA_HOME?

Since I'm using the openjdk (default in Ubuntu 10.04) I did the following to get it to work.

1. type java -version to see that it is installed

---

2. check if have the following path /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib

---

3. if the path exists then $sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc

---

4. add at the end of the file

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export PATH

---

5. save and exit

---

6. restart the terminal or open a new one and test the command (in my case $rosrun json_prolog json_prolog ias_semantic_map)

---

Originally posted by [joaoquintas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3707/joaoquintas/) with karma: 106 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0